# Regex works, but not in Angular Form

Tags: javascript, angular, regex, angular-reactive-forms

I need to use this regex for url validation. It works in regex101.com, but it fails validation in my Angular field. I don't know how to modify it in a way that Angular accepts.

regex: `https:\/\/[A-Za-z0-9_.~\/?%#!$&*+,;\[\]\(\)-]+`
url: `https://something.test.net/a-bc/x_y.json?ab=2021-08-11T`

I'm using Validators.pattern() in the form for the field validation.

I escaped the slashes with backslashes like shown above, but it still fails validation.

Answer (score -1):

In Angular, when using the **Validators.pattern()** method for form field validation, you don't need to escape the slashes with backslashes in your regular expression.

In the code above, I removed the backslashes before the forward slashes in your regex pattern. It should work correctly with Angular's Validators.pattern() method.

Here's the corrected version of your regex pattern without unnecessary backslashes:

```
Validators.pattern('https://[A-Za-z0-9_.~/?%#!$&*+,;\\[\\]()-]+')
```